# Angular 2 not loading external html for component

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

This might be a common issue, but i couldn't find anything that could help me.

I have set up an Angular environment within .Net Core following the official tutorial from typescriptlang.org. However, my root app component does not load the external template i have specified for it. When index.html loads, it just stays at the "Loading..." text specified initially. "test" should replace it.

Any ideas as to what i am doing wrong?

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { MyApp } from "./app";
bootstrap(MyApp);
```

**app.ts**

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core"

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

}
```

**app.html**

```
<span>test</span>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="scripts/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/rx.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/angular2.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            'scripts': {
                format: 'cjs',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('scripts/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the app.module.ts content?

Comment: Do you have a routing module?

Comment: The only other .ts file i have besides the one mentioned, is main.ts (bootstrapping). I have updated my original post with it's contents. That, together with the main component in app.ts, were the only ones mentioned to be a starting requirement at http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be atleast a module in your project,Thus create @NgModule inside app.module.ts (you should create) and bootstrap that module, which later bootstrap your component

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { MyApp } from './app';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp 
  ],      
  bootstrap: [MyApp ] // your component
})
export class AppModule { }// your module
```

In main.ts bootstrap your module as below //AppModule

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**So main will bootstrap your module which later bootstrap the component. In your code you were directly bootstraping component which wont work**

Comment: update pls?  If its working then mark it as an answer so that this answer help others as well.